# How to measure distance in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, measurement

How do you accurately measure the distance between 2 objects in InDesign? Is there a plug-in for that? Other than drawing a rectangle and putting it in between the objects for sizing. In Photoshop, for example, as I drag objects, it tells me the distance between the objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Gap Tool

[image: Gap tool]

1. Select the *Gap Tool*.
2. Mouse over the gap you want to measure.
3. Read the distance in the *Control* panel.

Comment: I’ve been using InDesign for a decade now, and I never noticed that tool before. Very handy!